# Deleting and updating data from database

Tags: html, perl

I have created a code that connects to database and i want to delete data from database using a button the same for update. but i just can display data in a table and cant delete.

```
  my $q= new CGI;
    print $q->header;
    print $q-> start_html(
       -title   => "",
    );

    # print $q->start_form;
    ## mysql user database name
    my $db = "people";
    ## mysql database user name
    my $user = "root"; 
    ## mysql database password
    my $pass = "";

    ## user hostname : This should be "localhost" but it can be diffrent too
    my $host="127.0.0.1";

    ## SQL query
    my $query = "select ID,Name,Surname,Gender from person";

    my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host", $user, $pass);
    my $sqlQuery  = $dbh->prepare($query)
    or die "Can't prepare $sqlQuery: $dbh->errstr\n";
    my $rv = $sqlQuery->execute
    or die "can't execute the query: $sqlQuery->errstr";

    print start_form (-method => 'post', -action => "modify.pl" );

    my @aRows;

    while (my @data = $sqlQuery->fetchrow_array()) {      
       my $cRowId = hidden('ID', $data[0]);

       my $bt1 = submit('action','delete');
       my $bt2 = submit('action','update');

       push @aRows, ($cRowId, $q->Tr($q->td([$data[1], $data[2], $data[3],$bt1,$bt2])));
    }

    print $q->table({-border =>'1', -align =>'center',  -width => '100%'},
       $q->Tr([$q->th([ 'Name', 'Surname', 'Gender', 'Delete', 'Update', ])]),
       @aRows,
    );

    print $q->input({-type => 'button', -class => 'button', -onclick => "window.location.href='insert.pl';", -value => 'Shto'});

    print $q->end_form;  
    print $q->end_html;
```

delete.pl

```
use CGI;
use CGI qw(standard);
use DBI;
use CGI::Carp qw(set_die_handler);
use CGI qw/:all/;
    BEGIN {
       sub handle_errors {
          my $msg = shift;
          print "content-type: text/html\n\n";
          #proceed to send an email to a system administrator,
          #write a detailed message to the browser and/or a log,
          #etc....
      }

      set_die_handler(\&handle_errors);
}

my $q = CGI->new();



my $db = "people";
my $user = "root"; 
my $pass = "";
my $host="127.0.0.1";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host", $user, $pass);
my $action = $q->param('action'){
given ($action){
           when('delete'){
               my $row_id = $q->param('ID');
               my $sth = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM person WHERE ID = $row_id ") or die "Can't prepare $query: $dbh->errstr\n";
               my $rv = $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;               
               print "deleted";
my $sth->finish();           
my $dbh->commit or die $DBI::errstr;
          }
    } }
```

I dont know where may be the problem

Comment: Do you really connect with the root user? Do you realize that your code is full of gruesome security holes and that I could wipe out your entire database if I knew the URL for your script?

Comment: Yes i connct because it diplays the value of database but just cant perform the delete action:http://localhost/cgi-bin/ova/laura/persona.pl and http://localhost/cgi-bin/ova/laura/modify.pl

Answer (score 3):

The vast majority of Perl CGI problems can be solved by:

- Adding `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code
- Fixing all of the errors that now appear in your error log

Answer (score 2):

You assign a value to `$row_id` **after** you try to use that variable to create your query.

Additionally, using raw user input in SQL queries makes you vulnerable to [XSS attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/). Rewrite your code to use [parameterized queries](http://bobby-tables.com/perl.html)

Comment: Move the line that defines the query so it appears after the line where you assign a value to that variable…

Comment: just edited but it doesnt work :Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: That you have *another* problem. Pay attention to the last sentence of the material you just quoted in that comment.

Comment: yes but there is nothing. Could you please edit my code if u know where may be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `my` if you do not want a new variable. Remove all `my`'s from the method calls:

```
my $sth->finish();           
my $dbh->commit or die $DBI::errstr;
```