# Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at

Tags: perl

I want to insert data into a database but it shows me the following error: `Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/cgi-bin/ova/laura/shto.pl line 47.`

```
 my $q= new CGI;
    print $q->header;
    print $q-> start_html(
       -title   => " ",
    );

    my $db   = "peoples";
    my $user = "root"; 
    my $pass = "";
    my $host ="127.0.0.1";
    my $dbh  = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host", $user, $pass);
    my $name            = $q->param("Name");
    my $surname         = $q->param("Surname");
    my $$gender         = $q->param("Gender");
    my $dId = $q->param("pID");
    my $departamentiId  = $q->param("dID");

    my $sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name, Surname, Gender, pID, dID)
               VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$gender','$pId','$dId')";

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
    my $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
    my $sth->finish();
    my $dbh->commit or die $DBI::errstr;
```

What may be the error?

Comment: Add `use warnings` to your code. Read documentation to find out what `my` is used for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `my` form the lines where you do not want to declare a new variable.

Using `use warnings` would have told you:

```
"my" variable $sth masks earlier declaration in same scope at -e line 1.
```

Also, use placeholders to construct SQL queries, they are [safer](http://bobby-tables.com):

```
my $sql = 'INSERT INTO personi (Emri, Mbiemri, Seksi, Pozicioni_ID, Departamenti_ID)
           VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$sth->execute($emri, $mbiemri, $gjinia, $pozicioniId, $departamentiId) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: ok thank you it works now. please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852904/deleting-and-updating-data-from-database   i cant find the problem and i really need it today

Comment: @Armida: Same error. Use warnings, do not use `my` for method calls.

Comment: please edit it because it still doesn't work. I really need your help

Comment: syntax error at C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/cgi-bin/ova/laura/modify.pl line 35, near "){" Global symbol "$row_id" requires explicit package name at C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/cgi-bin/ova/laura/modify.pl line 38. Global symbol "$sth" requires explicit package name at C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/cgi-bin/ova/laura/modify.pl line 38. syntax error at C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/cgi-bin/ova/laura/modify.pl line 43, near "}" Execution of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/cgi-bin/ova/laura/modify.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @Armida: You probably removed more `my`'s than needed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is these 2 lines:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
my $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
```

They should read:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
```

The reason is that the second line's `my` you had re-declared the variable `$sth` (thus erasing the old variable $sth which contained the STH object); upon re-declaration, the new `$sth` will - like all newly declared variables - be initialized to `undef`.

You should read the following documentation to understand variable scoping in Perl:

- [Variable Scoping in Perl: the basics](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=66677) on PerlMonks
- [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) on Perldoc
- [perlvar on perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly piggybacking on choroba's answer.  I also prefer to make sure that the "default" values returned from "param()" are rational, a la:

```
my $emri            = $q->param("Emri")           || undef;
my $mbiemri         = $q->param("Mbiemri")        || "August";
my $gjinia          = $q->param("Gjinia")         || 0;
my $pozicioniId     = $q->param("pozicioniId")    || "none";
my $departamentiId  = $q->param("departamentiId") || 82.4;
```

"param()" returns "undef" for missing values.  Even when parameterizing the query that undef value might not be what you anticipated.

Comment: An incoming value of '0' is going to trigger your defaults; just something to be aware of - if, say, a valid value of pozicioniId was '0'.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the zero value. I only hoped to share a sample of a technique that is simple and works if you have some knowledge of your inbound data.  I have not tried this but you could do something like `my $foo = defined($q->param("foo")) ? $q->param("foo") : "a default value";`

Comment: You could also use "//" which is "||" only checking for definedness rather than truthiness (from Perl 5.10 and up, I think).